# Can't get a class name by jQuery

Tags: jquery

I would like to get a class name of a known div, with a known id:

```
<div id="medi_s_t1" class="minitreatment doneNormal" onmouseover="MedicalRecord.showHint(this, 'http://pics.kapihospital.de/medi_s_t1.jpg', 'zmierzyć temperaturę?');" onmouseout="MedicalRecord.closeHint(this);" onclick="MedicalRecord._onclick(this, 170259146);"></div>
```

So I wanted to use this:

```
$('medi_s_t1').attr('class')
```

But chrome console gives me an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).attr is not a function
```

I've searched a bit about that, but I can't figure this out here is a whole screenshot with this error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRFRw.png

Comment: That usually means that you didn't include jQuery. And you're missing the `#` in `$('medi_s_t1')`. Fix that and it works https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/a9gusq6b/

Comment: Try using `jQuery('#medi_s_t1')` rather than `$`

Comment: Have you looked at the screenshot that I've linked? In this situation i think `$("medi_s_t1")` should not work, but it does..

Comment: I've tried that also, for some reason `$('#medi_s_t1')` give me `null`

Comment: Try just typing $ in the console: that should display information about the function being called... it would appear $() isn't jquery.

Comment: here is an output of `$`: `function $(b){if(arguments.length>1){for(var a=0,d=[],c=arguments.length;a<c;a++){d.push($(arguments[a]))}return d}if(Object.isString(b)){b=document.getElementById(b)}return Element.extend(b)}`

Answer (score 0):

You missed the "#" when you try to get element by ID so it is not a JQuery object yet. It caused the issue, the correct one is: $('#medi_s_t1').attr('class').

Comment: not using the `#` would only result in an empty jQuery object, not a non-jQuery object.